# Sending mail in asp .net when using proxy server with authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, proxy

I want to send mail using asp .net visual studio. Is there any way that i can send the mail when using proxy server authentication.I have include the proxyserveraddress in the web.config file but it does'nt help.I am using the smtp.gmail.com server with port number 587.Can I do so??

Comment: Please provide more details how you want to authenticate proxy? as proxy authentication is not required to send mail using gmail.

Comment: I am on a network that uses proxy server.so all my requests require proxy authentication.